# why it is asking for a token?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I've written a very simple llvm IR code. However when I try to run it through llc, I get the following error:

```
llc: add_test.ll:10:16: error: expected value token   
%r = load i32, i32* %retval
             ^
```

Here is the code:
    target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
    target triple = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %retval
  %r = load i32, i32* %retval

  ret i32 0
}

attributes #0 = { nounwind uwtable "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }

!llvm.ident = !{!0}

!0 = metadata !{metadata !"clang version 3.5.0 "}
```

The command that i'm running is llc add-test.ll

Does anybody know what could be the problem?

Comment: Which version of LLVM are you using?

Comment: @sepp2k clang is 3.5.0, which I assume makes LLVM version 3.5.0. I can't use newer version of LLVM, for my project I'm required to use a given version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for `load` (among others) was changed in LLVM version 3.7. The syntax you're using is the new one. Since you're using version 3.5, you need to use the old syntax, which is:

```
%r = load i32* %retval
```

In other words you only specify the type of the parameter, not of the result.

I assume the problem occurred because you're using the current version of the documentation while using an old version of LLVM. The documentation for LLVM 3.5.0 can be found [here](http://llvm.org/releases/3.5.0/docs/LangRef.html#load-instruction).